# QGis GDAL Grid Inverse Distance to a power - Grid Size

Tags: qgis, gdal, inverse-distance-weighted

When I run this function from QGis on a point shapefile, there is no option to determine the grid pixel size / resolution or dimensions. Am I missing something here?

Comment: If we speak about Interpolation/IDW interpolation from the Processing Toolbox, there are four fields in the output raster size section to set the output pixel size or number of rows/columns.

Comment: Yes, the exact command is Processing Toolbox > GDAL > Raster Analysis > Grid (Inverse distance to a power). There is no output pixel size field when I run it.